# Allow two widgets for a taxonomy term reference field (hierarchical select dropdown and autocomplete)?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

This may be impossible, but here's my situation.  I have a taxonomy called **Hobbies** which includes a rather large number of terms (300) in a hierarchy.

In their profiles, users have a term reference field so that they can list their hobbies.

Right now, I'm using the [Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select/) module, which displays the hierarchy cleanly and is great for browsing.

However, users often have trouble finding the term they are looking for because it is not under the parent term that they expect.  So, I would like to have an autocomplete option as well.

Is there some way in Drupal 7 to provide users with both a way to browse (like in Hierarchical Select) and to do direct input (like the core autocomplete)?

I am fairly certain there is no way to put two widgets on the same page, but is there some way to provide a second widget via an alternate interface?

Comment: If you can change the widget to use [SHS](https://drupal.org/project/shs) instead, and install the [Chosen module](https://drupal.org/project/chosen), I believe you can [get that functionality](https://drupal.org/node/1904480). I've never tried it though

Comment: Autocomplete Deluxe https://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe may be help you or finder module